# Highcharts add legend on export

Tags: highcharts, legend

I'm trying to add a legend on a pie when exporting the chart as PNG.
Here is my code :

```
var chart_23_106;
$(document).ready(function () {
chart_23_106 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: { type: 'pie', renderTo: 'container_23_106', plotBackgroundColor: null, plotBorderWidth: null, plotShadow: false },
    title: { text: 'NRJ' },
    tooltip: { pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}%</b>', percentageDecimals: 1 },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: { borderWidth: 0, shadow: false, allowPointSelect: true, cursor: 'pointer', dataLabels: { enabled: false } }
    },
    colors: ['#9F9F9F','#BE6EBE','#FFA74F','#B7B7D0','#CBE22A','#00C8C8'],
    credits: { enabled: false, text: "Source: Air Normand", href: "" },
    exporting:{ buttons: {
            printButton: {enabled:false},
            exportButton: {menuItems:null,onclick:function(){this.exportChart(null, 
                                        { chart: {reflow: false, width: 400}, 
                                          title: {text: "Répartition de la Consommation"}, 
                                          subtitle: {text: "Haute-Normandie"}, 
                                          plotOptions: {pie: {dataLabels: {enabled: true}, showInLegend: true}}, 
                                          credits: {enabled: true} }
                                    );}}
    }},
    lang: {exportButtonTitle: "Export image au format PNG"},
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Proportion',
        data: [
        ['Activite 1',   684.6],
        ['Activite 2',   564.7],
        ['Activite 3',   244.4],
        ['Activite 4',   42.8],
        ]
    }]
});
});
```

In the function exportChart, all but the plotOptions gives the right effect. In the PNG file, the title is changed, subtitle and credits are added, but the dataLabels and the legend don't appear...
Anyone knowing why ?
Could anyone help me ?
Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Yes it is possible by disabling legend in chart and in exporting parameters (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.chartOptions) set this option as active.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/xvQNA/

```
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2010'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}%</b>',
            percentageDecimals: 1
        },
        legend:{
            enabled:false
        },
        exporting:{
            chartOptions:{
                legend:{
                    enabled:true
                }
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#000000',
                    connectorColor: '#000000',
                    formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %';
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            showInLegend:true,
            data: [
                ['Firefox',   45.0],
                ['IE',       26.8],
                {
                    name: 'Chrome',
                    y: 12.8,
                    sliced: true,
                    selected: true
                },
                ['Safari',    8.5],
                ['Opera',     6.2],
                ['Others',   0.7]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked when i disabled the navigation in the exporting options :

```
  exporting: {
    chartOptions: {
      legend: {
        navigation: {
          enabled: false
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

you just should add  `enable: true` in dataLabels:

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
            }
        }
    }
```