# Printing a highchart to show data for all the points

Tags: highcharts

I have this chart:

http://jsfiddle.net/ECAM9/1/

And it works fine.

However when I print or export it, I want the resulting image or pdf file to look like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/rFzTG/

That means that I want every point to have info over it.

I was looking at this answer:

[Highcharts add legend on export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358333/highcharts-add-legend-on-export)

And I tried adding this:

```
exporting:{
            chartOptions:{
                scatter: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        formatter: function() {
                            return this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+ this.x +': '+ this.y +'°C';
                        }
                    },
                }
            }
        },
```

But again, the jpg file I print is without the info.

Comment: @SebastianBochan Can you check this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

1) use 'useHTML' in the datalabels

2) on chart load event, hide the datalabel elements

The chart will display without datalabels, since you hid them, but print with datalabels, since the chart was created with them

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/Z7csw/

```
dataLabels: {
  enabled: true,
  useHTML:true,
  formatter: function() {
    return '<div class="datalabel">' +this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
            this.x +': '+ this.y +'°C</div>';
  }
},
```

.

```
events:{
  load:function() {
    $('.datalabel').hide();
  }
}
```

**EDIT: -->**
Ok, I have a quick example that works with printing here, based on comments below:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/Z7csw/6/

It's not perfect, but it does work...

Comment: This worked, tnx! But it works only for export. How to make it work on print too?

Comment: Hm...not sure, I thought that would work for both :/ May need to use an external control...you can capture a button click, enable the datalabels, print the chart, and hide the datalabels...?

Comment: Looking here: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/exporting/buttons-contextbutton-menuitems/ and here: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/chart-print/ it looks like that's a viable option